# How to remove the warning unreachable code in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, visual-studio-code, return-value

```
function App() {
  return (

  <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Statistics} />
        <Route path='/' exact component={Overview} />
        <Route path='/' exact component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path='/' exact component={Analytics} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
  
  < MyMap />;
}
```

I am not getting the output and the code is reaching without loading the map.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) around both the `<Router>` and `<MyMap />` so you can render both

Comment: Yes. Is there a way to do both? Please help me.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear from the link and the duplicate post, use something like `return (<><Router> ... </Router><MyMap /></>)`